# VBA Code Giving Error on g = Sheet7.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to balance NBA stats. I'm getting an error with this function and don't know why. Sheets 5 and 6 and identical to Sheet 7. Confused why I'd be getting the error on Sheet 7 if all are identical. Also the code is the exact same for Sheet5 and Sheet 6 so shouldn't that remain the same for 7? I'm newer to VBA coding so trying to get any help even if it's simple.  It just asks to debug and takes me directly here. Happy to share more code if needed

```
    'Function to Obtain Team's Season Average Raw Stats
Function Grab_Team_Raw(t As String, team As String)
    
    If t = "All" Then
        
        a = 2
        g = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Find Team's Row First
        
        For a = 2 To g
        
            tm = Sheet5.Cells(a, 1).Value
            If tm = team Then
                rw = a
            End If
        
        Next a
        
        a = 2
        g = Sheet5.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For a = 2 To g
            v = Sheet5.Cells(rw, a).Value
            output = output & "," & v
        Next a
        
    ElseIf t = "Home" Then
    
        a = 2
        g = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For a = 2 To g
        
            tm = Sheet6.Cells(a, 1).Value
            If tm = team Then
                rw = a
            End If
        
        Next a
        
        a = 2
        g = Sheet6.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For a = 2 To g
            v = Sheet6.Cells(rw, a).Value
            output = output & "," & v
        Next a
        
    Else
    
        a = 2
        g = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For a = 2 To g
        
            tm = Sheet7.Cells(a, 1).Value
            If tm = team Then
                rw = a
            End If
        
        Next a
        
        a = 2
        g = Sheet7.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For a = 2 To g
            v = Sheet7.Cells(rw, a).Value
            output = output & "," & v
        Next a
        
    End If
    
    Grab_Team_Raw = output

End Function
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: How are you passing your parameter's to your function and what values are you using?

Comment: My guess is the is not set and is 0

Comment: @scottCraner the error is Run-time error '1004;: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Then rw is 0. Your if never returns true.

Comment: @TimWilliams towards the bottom:         g = Sheet7.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: If you hover the mouse over `rw` while in break mode, what is its value?

Comment: rw is empty when I hover over it

Comment: That indicates that Scott is correct- on Sheet7 there's no match (and you should add a check to your code for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half the effort needed for coding goes into designing variables, find their proper data types, and "meaningful" names for them. Start with **Option Explicit**.

```
Option Explicit

Function Grab_Team_Raw(t As String, team As String) As Variant
    ' Obtain Team's Season Average Raw Stats
    ' return a 2-D array of one row's data
    
    Dim Ws      As Worksheet            ' working object
    Dim Rw      As Long                 ' loop counter: row
    
    Select Case t
        Case "All"
            Set Ws = Sheet5
        Case "Home"
            Set Ws = Sheet6
        Case Else
            Set Ws = Sheet7
    End Select
    
    'Find Team's row
    For Rw = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = team Then Exit For
    Next Rw
    If Rw > 1 Then
        With Ws                         ' observe all leading periods
            Grab_Team_Raw = .Range(.Cells(Rw, 1), _
                                   .Cells(Rw, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox team & " not found."
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

I guess that your problem hails from this line of code which my above procedure inherited from the one you posted: *If Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = team*. Try `If StrComp(Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value, team, vbTextCompare) = 0` instead which makes the comparison case insensitive. But what you really need is a drop-down from which you select the names so that typos can be definitely ruled out.

Note that the function will return a 1-based 2-D array of one row. Access its elements like MyArr(1, Clm). The row is always 1 because there is only one row. The column matches the sheet column. A = 1, B = 2, etc. You wanted the array to start with column B which would have made B = 1, C = 2, etc. You can change that back in this line of code, `Grab_Team_Raw = .Range(.Cells(Rw, 1), _`